# vim's function to global search and paste in-place

Tags: vim, neovim

Working on HTML files from vim, I'm used to deal with dummy anchors like `<a id="@"></a>`, such as I can check my progress on my browser using `<url>#@` anchor.

I usually start my session recording a macro:

```
mz
:g;<a id="@"></a>;d<CR>
'z
p
```

This macro basically mark my current position, global/delete my pattern, and paste at the initial location.

Now, I would like to turn this into a function; this is my attempt:

```
function! PprojLoc()
    " get current location for further paste
    let rownb=line(".")
    " define dummy anchor to work on
    let pattern='^<a id="@"></a>$'
    " build the global command to search and delete
    " '/' separator is changed to ';'
    let cmd=":g;".pattern.";d<CR>"
    " delete pattern <DOESN'T WORK>
    execute cmd
    " back to initial location
    execute "normal! ".rownb."G"
    " paste...
    execute "normal! p"  
endfunction
```

Unfortunately, the `normal!` command `cmd` doesn't work at all. any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I nailed it in a single command.

```
:execute "normal! mz" | execute "g;<a id="@"></a>;m'z"
```

One observation: In order to use the pipe symbol -> `|`, both in normal and global commands you have to use the execute notation as seen above because the consider that symbol as part of the command, not another command.

So, we are creating a mark "z" as if we were in normal mode, this will set the current cursor position to the z mark. The global command will match the lines you want and move them "`m`" to the z mark.

At the moment I do not recall a way to save the z mark if it already exists, as a way of preserving it, making the command more transparent. If anyone could solve this problem I would thank a lot.

```
" If mark "a" is set it will return a positive value
:ec getpos("'a")[1]
```

Building a function we can pass the search as function argument making the code more portable.